# how do i properly clean std::wcin stream from errors

Tags: c++, c++17, cin

I need the program to read the text until it encounters EOF generated by Ctrl + Z and then write it into some file

```
wstring texttowrite;
wstring line;
while (getline(wcin, line)) texttowrite.append(line + L'\n');
```

It works fine but I can't get wcin stream working after. Wcin.clear() + wcin.ignore(numeric_limits ::max(), L'\n') doesn't do the trick for me

Comment: just curious, what do you want to do with `wcin` after it has read until the end?

Comment: why it doesnt work? Please show not only the code that does work but also the code that does not. See also [mcve]

Comment: Once a stream ends, it can't magically un-end. Perhaps using Ctrl+Z as a delimiter was not a wise choice.